# How can I best share settings between Windows IoT Core apps?

Tags: raspberry-pi, settings, windowsiot

I'm developing an "headless" background application that runs under Windows 10 IoT Core on a Raspberry Pi 3. However, I need a way for the user to configure the application. One way I have considered doing this is to have a separate "headed" application that the user can run to view and edit the various parameters. I could also make a web app so that no display is necessary on the Raspberry Pi.

I can't see any obvious mechanism for sharing settings between apps, or for that matter even creating persistent settings for a single app. On a desktop app I would just use the normal `Properties.Settings.Default` object. Is there a Universal Windows Platform equivalent of the App Settings API?

Comment: Have you checked ["Using cross-app communication to make apps work together "](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/22/using-cross-app-communication-to-make-apps-work-together-10-by-10/#fWpJHIB0Lf2bliYS.97)?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Thanks for that link, it looks like there is some solid information there. That covers the inter-app communication, but what about persisting settings? Is there a standard way of doing that in UWP?

Comment: Persisting settings, you mean these settings will not change even the app is uninstalled?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I hadn't considered uninstallation, but if I were writing a Desktop app then I would use Properties.Settings.Default and my settings would be saved in an XML file somewhere. What I'm asking, I guess, is what's the equivalent for UWP apps? There must be some facility for saving settings, surely? What's the best practice in UWP?

Comment: Have you check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data)?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT you did it again, that looks like a really solid set of guidelines. Thanks for responding. If you are motivated to write this up in an answer then I will mark it 'accepted'. Otherwise I may write something up myself once I've had a chance to try these resources out.

Comment: I write the answer. Please check it.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Marked as 'accepted' as promised. Please conside upvoting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't see any obvious mechanism for sharing settings between apps

You can check "[Using cross-app communication to make apps work together](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/22/using-cross-app-communication-to-make-apps-work-together-10-by-10/#wIzW12xPamLVZ0Xz.97)".

> creating persistent settings for a single app

For UWP, each app has system-defined root directories that you can use it for storing. The system also preserves the contents of these data stores until your app is uninstalled. 
You can store and retrieve setting like this:

```
// Store settings
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["setting1"] = "test1";
localSettings.Values["setting2"] = "test2";

// Retrieve settings
var value1 = localSettings.Values["setting1"];
var value2 = localSettings.Values["setting2"];
```

For more information you can reference "[Store and retrieve settings and other app data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data)".

Comment: Great answer! I'm sure lots of people will find that useful. If you do, then please remember to vote up both question and answer!